# How to use PUT method to create object in Django

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework, put

How to use PUT method for creating an object on particular id if no object is available
on that id in Django Rest Framework?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`update_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create)

e.g:

```
class YourAPIView(APIView):

    def put(self, request, **kwargs):
        serializer = YourSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        obj, created = YourModel.objects.update_or_create(
        id=kwargs['id'],
        defaults=serializer.validated_data)
        return Response()
```

Answer (score 0):

A RESTFUL API should error out for a PUT request on an object that doesn't exist. The idea being that if it had existed at one point to create the id, it has since been deleted. It makes more sense to keep it deleted than to re-create it.

This is especially true if the id is auto-generated. And even more so if it's an auto-incrementing integer id like the default id of Django models. If you were to support this functionality in that case, a user would create an instance of data with an id that the table hasn't incremented over yet [potentially leading to errors like this.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46125/why-does-postgres-generate-an-already-used-pk-value)